# How to calculate the height of an iframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the height of the page shown within the iframe using

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.outerHeight
```

contentWindow.outerHeight takes different values in different browsers and does not really give the right height value. Also, in internet explorer, I see an error "Access is denied".

The page I am trying to show within the iframe does not have any problems loading.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_iframe_height.asp

Comment: I believe the wording of your question awkwardly reflects what you are trying to achieve. From your code example it looks like you want to get the height of the page shown within an `<iframe />` element and then set the iframe to be that height to get rid of scroll bars, is that correct? If so then you're going to run into these access policies that make doing that more difficult than you might think. You should take a look at postMessage, there's a great jQuery plugin however you can also do this in vanilla JS. The basic idea is to send messages between the inner and outer pages.

Comment: @Craig, thethe w3schools url does not give me the height. In my case, it is null.

Comment: @Jasper. Yes. I am trying to get the height of the page shown within the iframe. However, I do not have any access problems with the page I am trying to display.

Comment: @Anonymous That's what the `Access is denied` message is all about. The outer page is not being given access to the inner one, it's a security issue. To have access between the outer page and inner page like you want, make sure you are on the exact same domain for both and you are using the exact same protocol on both. There may be other solutions than the one I've suggested but I suggest it because it's worked for me and doesn't break when someone does something like remove `www` from the domain when accessing the outer page.

Comment: You will want to research the "Same Origin Policy." Here's a good starting place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 2):

Since you do get values in some browsers but not IE, I'll assume this is *not* a cross-domain issue.

`contentWindow.outerHeight` doesn't work for me in IE unless I add:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

The following seems to work best across all browsers:

```
contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
```

Note that different browsers render HTML slightly differently, depending on CSS defaults, wrapping algorithms, etc.  So you're unlikely to get the same height in one browser as you would in another.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out:

- [JQuery iFrame Resizer](https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height)
- [iFrame Resizer](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/)
- [Support for cross domain iframe resizing](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/)
- [jQuery Resize Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/)